# std::cin and units library

Tags: c++, cin, units-of-measurement

I'm having a problem with a program I'm making when I try to ask the user to enter a value and then saving it to use it later in a formula.

This what I have done, the problem is that I can't use `std::cin` because is not a defined type, but I have tried to change the type (with
`static_cast<dimless_t>`) and I couldn't do it without making the output wrong, despite there were any errors.

This code is without trying to change the type.

```
// ISO C++20:
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>   // contiene std::sqrt
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <numbers>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// ISO C++23:
#include <cppexten/generator>
#include <cppexten/print>
#include <cppexten/ranges>

 

namespace stdx = std::experimental;

// biblioteca de terceros:
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp> // tokenizador para extraer los valores en una línea del CSV
#include <dlib/optimization.h> // contiene el método LM de regresión no-lineal

#include <units/format.h>
#include <units/math.h>
#include <units/isq/si/length.h>
#include <units/generic/dimensionless.h>
//#include <units/isq/si/electric_current.h>
#include <units/isq/si/electric_field_strength.h> // Por que ampere está aquí y no en electric_current?
#include <units/isq/si/magnetic_induction.h>
#include <units/isq/si/permeability.h>

namespace un = units;
namespace usi = units::isq::si;

using len_t = usi::length<usi::millimetre>; // Tipo de longitud en milimetros
using curr_t = usi::electric_current<usi::ampere>; // Tipo de corriente en Amperios
using mag_ind_t = usi::magnetic_induction<usi::millitesla>; // Tipo de intensidad del campo magnético en militeslas
using perm_t = usi::permeability<usi::henry_per_metre>; // Tipo de permeabilidad del vacío en Henry · metro^(-1)
using dimless_t = un::quantity<un::dim_one, un::one, float>; // Tipo sin unidades

    dimless_t const N ; // número de espiras, adimensional
    curr_t const I ; // Corriente que pasa por el solenoide en Amperios
    len_t const L ; // Longitud del solenoide en milímetros
    len_t const D ;

auto main() -> int 
{   

    std::cout<<"Insert number of loops of the solenoid: "; 
    std::cin>>N;

    std::cout<<"Insert intensity of the current: "; 
    std::cin>>I;

    std::cout<<"Insert lenght of the solenoid: "; 
    std::cin>>L;

    std::cout<<"Insert diametre of the solenoid: "; 
    std::cin>>D;

}
```

This is the output (I have the program done but I'm making some changes to make the user able to change things):

```
    Insert the path of the CSV file (C:/Users/user_name/Desktop/file_name.csv): C:\Users\Escritorio\Europea\Tercero\Computacion_avanzada\magnetic_data_no_z_correction.csv
    Factor de corrección z_0 = 5.28333 mm
    Permeabilidad magnética μ0 = 1.1579e-06 H/m | μ0/(4 * pi * 10^-7) = 0.92143 H/m
    RSE = 0.797024 mT
```

If I try to change the type doing this:

```
    float  cN ;
    float  cI ;
    float  cL ;
    float  cD ;
    auto  N = static_cast<dimless_t>(cN); // número de espiras, adimensional
    auto  I = static_cast<curr_t>(cI); // Corriente que pasa por el solenoide en Amperios
    auto  L = static_cast<len_t>(cL); // Longitud del solenoide en milímetros
    auto  D = static_cast<len_t>(cD);
```

I recive the next output which is wrong:

```
Insert number of loops of the solenoid: 100.0
Insert intensity of the current: 1.0
Insert lenght of the solenoid: 50.0
Insert diametre of the solenoid: 10.0
Insert the path of the CSV file (C:/Users/user_name/Desktop/file_name.csv):  C:\Users\alvar\OneDrive\Escritorio\Europea\Tercero\Computacion_avanzada\magnetic_data_no_z_correction.csv
Factor de corrección z_0 = 5 mm
Permeabilidad magnética μ0 = 1e-06 H/m | μ0/(4 * pi * 10^-7) = 0.795775 H/m
RSE = -nan mT
```

Comment: what is the output, what is the expected output? When talking about compiler errors you should post the compiler error message rather than rephrasing it. I can guess what compiler error you refer to but it has nothing to do with `std::cin` being a type that is not defined. `std::cin` is an object.

Comment: There are no stream extraction operators defined for those types. You need to read a number and then convert.

Comment: I think now is everything clear, the program has other functions that are not the problem

Comment: It's my first post here, I only have used StackExchange where you have to put a minimal work

Comment: There are broadly two approaches to input with units. One is to take input like `50mm`, parse the number and the unit suffix and check it's the expected type (and scale appropriately if the input is `5cm` or `0.05m` when you wanted mm). This is **lots** of work. The other is to take input as plain numbers and just assume they're the right units. You can always show the desired units in a prompt, or print them after input, but it's much much easier.

Comment: What `<units>` library are you using? Do they have `operator>>` defined on the types?

Comment: @Useless Can you make an example of the first approach?? It's a work for college and the thing with using units is to prevent any error when typing

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I'm using this one: `find_package(mp-units REQUIRED)` I really don't know what it comes with, but I think they have not the `operator>>`

Comment: No way, I said it's **lots** of work, and that means far to much to fit in an answer here (or to do for free for a complete stranger who is presumably supposed to be learning this themselves). However, if you look at the output operator ([here](https://github.com/mpusz/units/blob/master/src/core-io/include/units/quantity_io.h) or in your own code), you should at least be able to write an input operator that reads a number and checks it is followed by `detail::unit_text`. The hard part is scaling and conversion.

Comment: I'm really new into C++ and programming in general, I just know the things that I have learn in class (where we have skipped basic C++ to understand how the lenguage work) so I don't understand what that link is supossed to explain, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done and works:

```
std::cout<<"Insert number of loops of the solenoid: "; //Pedimos al usuario las diferentes constantes
std::cin>>N.number(); //Guardamos el valor numérico de lo introducido para usarlo a la hora de hacer funciones

std::cout<<"Insert intensity of the current: "; 
std::cin>>I.number();

std::cout<<"Insert lenght of the solenoid: "; 
std::cin>>L.number();

std::cout<<"Insert diametre of the solenoid: "; 
std::cin>>D.number();
```

Just add `.number()` to make `std::cin` save just the value